# How do you remove content from a div?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I remove all of the checkboxes in my div? If I use this then it removes my paragraph but prints each of the projcet names still, along with the 
 inbetween. (the checkbox is missing though)

```
$('#fileList').children().remove();
```

My html is:

```
<div id="fileList">
<p> Select which project files you would like to download: </p>
    <form id="files">
        <input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="1">Project File 1</input></br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="2">Project File 2</input></br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="3">Project File 3</input>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove them from the DOM or just hide them?

Comment: `<input/>`s are [empty elements](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201005/void_empty_elements_and_self-closing_start_tags_in_html/), so they shouldn't have a closing tag. Instead close them with a forward slash (`/`) before the greater than sign (`>`) like this: `<input type="checkbox"/>`. Same thing with `<br/>`s: The forward slash needs to go after the tag name, and before the greater than sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html is invalid, input tags does not have ending tags, try this instead

```
<div id="fileList">
    <p> Select which project files you would like to download: </p>
    <form id="files">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="1">Project File 1</label></br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="2">Project File 2</label></br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="3">Project File 3</label>
    </form>
</div>
```

with

```
$('#fileList label').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing them like this with a small modification in your HTML. As your label tags and the text are not an appropriate way of defining the checkbox with labels.

**[W3C recommendation on how to define a checkbox](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/checkbox)**

http://jsfiddle.net/tAzB2/

```
   $('#fileList  input:checkbox').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('label').remove();
});
```

The issue here is that you would need to use a label to wrap your checkboxes and remove them..

Have your html like this:-

```
<div id="fileList">
<p> Select which project files you would like to download: </p>
    <form id="files">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="idOfField" /> Some text</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="1">Project File 1</input></label></br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="2">Project File 2</input></label></br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="3">Project File 3</input></label>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This results in the same behavior above... each of the text inside the input is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this through the CSS selector:

```
$('#fileList input[type=checkbox]').remove();
```

Comment: This results in the same behavior above... each of the text inside the input is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
("#myDiv :checkbox").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the entire list try:

```
    $('#files').empty();
```

To keep everything intact except the boxes try:

```
    $('#fileList input:checkbox').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('#fileList  input:checkbox').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('label').remove();
});
```